# flowise server editing not reflecting in server

Tags: artificial-intelligence, large-language-model, flowise

I am trying to edit the flowise server code to include a few api endpoints. I have follow the dev instructions in the docs https://docs.flowiseai.com/getting-started however, when I start the app with the start command, I see all the packages running including the flowise server however, there is no log showing the server was started and I can't reach it through postman, please any help will be appreciated. Here are the screenshots below.
[image]
[image]
[image]